# AngularJS nested objects and $apply'ing the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an AngularJS based SPA and despite all the documentation, articles, questions etc that I've read, nothing is able to explain the situation I've come across.

The silly thing is, the last time I used Angular, I am pretty sure I had this problem and found a solution. I just can't find that same solution again.

Anyhoo... Basically I have a nested object,

```
$scope.campaign = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    limitations: 0,
    interactions: {
        follow: false,
        dm: false,
        message: ''
    },
    options: [
        { handle: '', hashtag: '' }
    ]
};
```

and I've got a repeater on `campaign.options` which based on the initial values, works great.

I then have some scope functions hooked on `ng-click` to add a new item to campaign.options

```
$scope.addOption = function() {
    $scope.campaign.options.push({
        handle: '',
        hashtag: ''
    });
}
```

The above silently fails, however if I add a `$watch` for `campaign`, it fires every time I click the button hooked to addoption.

If I try using $apply either as `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$apply(fn)` I get the generic `inprog` error.

Can anyone shed some light on this other than simply reverting back to using a single layer object.

Edit: Sorry, I don't think I pointed out what the issue is...

Despite the fact that I can see the `$scope.campaigns` array containing an additional item each time I click `addOption` the UI is not updating to reflect it however if I manually set `$scope.campaigns` to contain a number of items on page load, it renders correctly, so it appears not to be updating when I modify the scope.

Sigh....

Second edit:

My repeater:

```
<label>Enter the applicable options for this competition</label>
<div class="list-group">
    <p ng-if="!campaign.options">This competition needs some possible answers.</p>
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeater="(idx, option) in campaign.options">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-margin">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="option.handle" placeholder="Handle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-margin">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">#</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="option.hashtag" placeholder="Hashtag">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a class="btn btn-block btn-danger" ng-click="removeOption(idx)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-click="addOption()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add a new option</a>
```

The error I receive when attempting to call `$scope.$apply()` is:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)
    at http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at p (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:118:370)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:126:224)
    at n.$scope.addOption (http://domain.com/app/controllers/app/campaigns/add/competition.js:32:20)
    at ib.functionCall (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:199:303)
    at Ec.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:216:74)
    at n.$get.n.$eval (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:126:15)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:126:241)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://domain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:216:126)
```

Comment: No need of scope.$apply... Can you show us the repeater, how do yu call that method on the scope and what error do you see ?

Comment: Come on Gavin, show us your ng-repeat HTML.

Comment: Well. i have never heard of an `ng-repeat`er.. ;) What version of angular you are using btw and what error do you see in your console without scope.apply..

Comment: WTF... I'll pack my bags and leave now...

Comment: XD nice catch @PSL I went all the way creating a plunker not understanding why it didn't work http://plnkr.co/edit/2LIdjvH29Z0iOhLZNq4z?p=preview

Comment: I was literally about to do that my to go look, see, it's not working... FML! As stupid as it is, it's still a valid question/answer for anyone else out there. Can you pop an answer on and I'll mark it as complete. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Gavin this is actually a typo so you may want to remove the question or get it flagged as typo... Also please do not use scope.apply everywhere you generally wouldn't need it and using it undauntedly will throw errors like this. :)

Comment: @PSL I knew that'd be the case, however due to my stupidity, I thought it wasn't working so started thinking it was out of scope (not sure why) - In terms of flagging it, will see what I can do. Thank you again!

Comment: @Gavin No worries.. :) next time.. you could just re-read your code first before putting lot of effort in posting.. :) cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `track by $index` in your ng-repeat.

Otherwise, try simplifying and isolating the problem. I've done this exact sort of thing many times without issue.

Comment: Why did somebody give `-1`? `track by $index` is a good solution if he uses empty elements like in his example...

Comment: Not sure who -1'd it, but gave it a go with no luck, although I `could` be using it wrong.  `ng-repeater="(idx, option) in campaign.options track by idx"` - tried with and without $ on the idx?

Comment: I don't think tracking is an issue here

Comment: Just for clarity, you do not need to replace `$index`, `ng-repeat="(idx, option) in campaign.options track by $index"` works *as-is*.

Comment: You need to use `$index` verbatim